# Angular 2 - How do you call a function in a sibling component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 sibling components that need to communicate:

`<app-controls></app-controls>
 <app-main></app-main>`

app-controls contains buttons that need to trigger events in the app-main component. Is there a Angular 2 style guide compliant way of doing so?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a template variable to get a reference to the sibling.
If `<app-controls>` has an output where it emits events when a button is clicked you can do:

```
<app-controls (buttonClicked)="main.doSomething($event)"></app-controls>
<app-main #main></app-main>
```

or you can pass a reference to a `@Input() siblings;` and then call methods on it:

```
<app-controls [sibling]="main"></app-controls>
<app-main #main></app-main>
```

Comment: I was about to post an answer mentioning the output + local template variable technique, but you beat me :).  Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfqrMs7Rn3S9ZeYLvY83?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the Plunker :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how can i access the form inside the <app-main #main></app-main>  

please note for this #main  im loading a dynamic component

Comment: @LittleDragon Please create a new question with your code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer add a new question :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573260/angular-2-collect-data-from-a-sibling-component

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the solution

Comment: @MarkRajcok That plunker help me the easy way

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It will give error when you build for prod :)

Comment: @Fooker quite pointless comment without the actual error message :)

Comment: this approach shows main undefined for me so I had to use event emitter in the service and subscribe in the component to trigger event

Comment: Looks like you can also create a ViewChild reference to component A and then assign it to a public variable in component B from the parent component which can then be referenced from within component B.  I had to do that to avoid the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError as I had an *ngIf on component A.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

Use a shared Service with dependency injection.

Or using the `@Input()` und `@Output()` decorators:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html