# Sibling event communication in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have five components in my project at the time which are

```
1: AppComponent (Main component)
2: AuthComponent
3: HomeComponent
4: HeaderComponent
5: FooterComponent
```

Html for "AppComponent" is

```
<section class="app content-area">
<ng2-slim-loading-bar  [height]="'4px'"></ng2-slim-loading-bar>
<fds-header *ngIf="_appDataService.isLoggedIn"></fds-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<fds-footer></fds-footer>
```

Now "HomeComponent" and "AuthComponent" is rendering in "router-outlet" and "AuthComponent" have method for login and logout. In "HeaderComponent" there is a button for logout and when it clicked I want to call logout method of "AuthComponent". Now here I cannot use "Template variable" for "AuthComponent" 
[as answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004684/angular-2-how-do-you-call-a-function-in-a-sibling-component) because it is rendering in "router-outlet". So how it can be done?

Comment: You can use a common service as mentioned by ranakrunal9, but for communication between sibling component you can use eventemitter also, check out this anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685801/angular-2-event-catching-between-sibling-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create one common service which shared between your `HeaderComponent` and `AuthComponent` and with this service you can communicate between `HeaderComponent` and `AuthComponent`. Check [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) documentation and my answer for [parent-child comunication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2/39739184#39739184)

Comment: but "HeaderComponent" and "AuthComponent" are siblings not parent child

Comment: I have used "Subject" it work fine but when I refresh the page then it no longer work.

Comment: you can use common service to communicate between siblings `HeaderComponent` and `AuthComponent`

Comment: On log out button click in `HeaderComponent`, you need to emit the method from your service which needs to be already subscribed by `AuthComponent` so that you can perform your action on event trigger

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you describe but when I refresh the page then it does not work. first time without refreshing the page it work.

Comment: can you please explain, on page refresh whats not working ? because i do not have any idea on page refresh what you have implemented and how.

Comment: I have used a common service between "AuthComponent" and "HeaderComponent" and on click of logout button I have used this line "this.logoutService.notifyOther(true)" and in "AuthComponent" I am catching this event. When first time I logged in and then without doing anything when I clicked logout this event is catch successfully in AuthComponent but when I refresh the page or go to any other state then on logout click nothing happen means AuthComponent does not catch the event.

Comment: it should work may be some thing else is blocking it. share your code or create plunker to show the issue

Comment: I found out what is the issue. After login user is redirected to dashboard state and when I refresh the dashboard state whole application is re-initialized and this time "AuthComponent" is not created so AuthComponent is not registered to catch event. So how I can handle this situation.