# Communication between sibling components Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need to create a click even on one component, that will display sibling component inside their parent component, but not sure how to do it. I understand parent/child communication using Input and Output, but this is not working like that.

So I have this structure:

- -Parent Component
- -- Child One
- -- Child Two

So they are in my parent component's html,

```
<app-child-one></app-child-one>
<app-child-two></app-child-two>
```

Child One and Child Two components are both popups, so on a click in Parent component I display the Child One component (popup now), and inside that popup I have button Next, that should show the Child Two component.

I can't nest Child Two inside Child One since there are many more popups and I would like to keep it somewhat organized.

**Here's my code:**

Parent component:

```
<app-one *ngIf="popupOne" [(popupOne)]="popupOne"></app-one>
<app-two *ngIf="popupTwo" [(popupTwo)]="popupTwo"></app-two>
```

both `popupOne` and `popupTwo` are set to false.

Component one:

```
Input() popupOne: boolean; 
Input() popupTwo: boolean; 
Output() popupOneChange= new EventEmitter<boolean>(); 
Output() popupTwoChange= new EventEmitter<boolean>(); 
close() { this.popupOne.emit(false); } 
openPopupTwo() { this.popupTwoChange.emit(true); }
```

Component Two:

```
Input() popupTwo: boolean;
```

Comment: create a service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: "I understand parent/child communication using Input and Output, but this is not working like that" - why not? the first child says to the parent that he's done; the parent will then switch to the second child.

Comment: @CosminAbabei I tried it, in parent I set to variable to false, input it in child one and output the change, input it inside te child two = not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421746

Comment: @grabnem Then there's something wrong in your code. It should work.

Comment: @CosminAbabei are you sure? i checked my code 10x it is not any different than other things ive done

Comment: @grabnem I don't see why not. Can you paste your code here?

Comment: @CosminAbabei

Parent component:
<app-one *ngIf="popupOne" [(popupOne)]="popupOne"></app-one> <app-two *ngIf="popupTwo" [(popupTwo)]="popupTwo"></app-two> both popupOne and popupTwo are set to false. 

Component one:

Input() popupOne: boolean;
Input() popupTwo: boolean;
Output() popupOneChange= new EventEmitter<boolean>();
Output() popupTwoChange= new EventEmitter<boolean>();

close() {
    this.popupOne.emit(false);
  }

  openPopupTwo() {
    this.popupTwoChange.emit(true);
  }

Component Two: 

Input() popupTwo: boolean;

This is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appOne` doesn't have the `popupTwo` variable registered as output on it.

Adding it, as `<app-one *ngIf="popupOne" [(popupOne)]="popupOne" [popupTwo]="popupTwo"></app-one>`, should solve your problem.