# Angular 2 how to collect data from a dynamic sibling component?

Tags: angular

hi all i have a 2 of same level component in my main component , one of my sibling component have a form and i need to collect that form data from another sibling component

```
 <tab [tabTitle]="'Quote'"> <div  #quotedetails></div> </tab>
```

`#quotedetails` - this load from dynamic used `ComponentFactoryResolver` , this include the form with data

here is my form

```
<form [formGroup]="policyForm">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="PostCode" placeholder="Post Code" />
</form >
```

and use FormBuilder for build controller in my component side

```
 policyForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

this.policyForm = this.fb.group({

PostCode : this.fb.control(null),


 }),

}
```

here is how i render dynamic component in my main component

```
 @ViewChild('quotedetails', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef;
    private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

 private children = {
        LHI: LHIComponent,
        Test: TestComponent
    };


ngAfterContentInit() {

        let childComponent = this.children['LHI'];

        let componentFactory = this.compiler.resolveComponentFactory(childComponent);
        this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(componentFactory);

    }


 constructor(private policyService: PolicyService, private compiler: ComponentFactoryResolver) {


    }
```

this is sibling view

```
<quote-summary  [policyDetail]="policyDetail" [summary]="summary" ></quote-summary>
```

so i need to assess the form in 'quote-summary' component

Comment: Please add the part that shows how you implement the form.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  done

Comment: Please also the code how you create the form.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer done

Comment: I don't get how `ComponentFactoryResolver` is involved here

Comment: update the ComponentFactoryResolver  part

Comment: I still can't see how this is related to the question or the form

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what i need is , there is a form in #quotedetails its a dynamic and i need to access that form in <quote-summary > component

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer   any idea abt this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637736/angular2-patchvalue-format-with-pipes