# angular2 patchvalue format with pipes

Tags: forms, angular

how can i use the value format with form contoller patchvalue  ?

when i use the ngModel i use value format like this

```
[ngModel]="policyModel?.amendmentDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
```

now i remove the ngModel and use the formcontroller and use the patchvalue  to set values

```
 this.policyForm
            .patchValue({

            AmendmentDate: this.policyModel.amendmentDate, 
  })
```

so how can i format this date -  amendmentDate

Comment: If you want to use date pipe then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607568/cannot-instantiate-datepipe

Comment: @yurzui  thank you very much its work !!!  :)