# Calling a method from child component in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

i want to call a method from child component(HomePage) in another child component(CustomPage) in ionic 2, without using any service.
i am using two components for two different tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use a template variable to get a reference to the sibling. If <app-controls> has an output where it emits events when a button is clicked you can do:
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004684/angular-2-how-do-you-call-a-function-in-a-sibling-component)

```
<app-controls (buttonClicked)="main.doSomething($event)"></app-controls>
<app-main #main></app-main>
or you can pass a reference to a @Input() siblings; and then call methods on it:

<app-controls [sibling]="main"></app-controls>
<app-main #main></app-main>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,
let me explain clearly.i hv a tab structure in my app,they are total 4 tabs present but i now including one more tab in app. 
The new tab is used to do the same actions which i done in all 4tabs  now i want  call the methods which already used in previous tabs.Means i need to call those methods from the new component.I hv old components A,B,C & D, Now i am creating new component E
1.COMP-A having Methods A1(),A2()
2.COMP-B having Methods B1(),B2().
3.COMP-C having Methods C1(),C2().
4.COMP-D having Methods D1(),D2().
now i want to invoke A2,B1,C1&D2 in my new COMP E