# Call function from other component into current in angular without any parent child relationship

Tags: angular

I want to call `myrole()` of **ComponentTwo**  in **componentOne** without parent child relation.
ComponentOne is main component. After click on  `MyRoleClick()` I want to call `myrole()` of ComponentTwo

```
export class ComponentOne{
  MyRoleClick(){
     want to call myrole() of ComponentTwo without parent child relation here.
  }
}

export class ComponentTwo{

 myrole(){

 }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - How do you call a function in a sibling component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004684/angular-2-how-do-you-call-a-function-in-a-sibling-component)

Comment: not a sibling component @Narm

Comment: Sounds like a sibling relationship. What is the relation of the components then, please provide more information and context.

Comment: They are independent component just two Component in different files to explain I have written one after another.

Comment: That still sounds like siblings. Could you provide some code that demonstrates how you plan to use these components in the HTML? You're question the way it stand looks almost identical to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2)

Comment: What do have in myrole() method? could u elaborate little bit of your requirement. May be there is a better approach to your issue rather calling a method in completely isolated component

Comment: @Narm The "possible duplicate" might not help if the components are not included in the same file.

Comment: As one of the answers to the duplicate shows, all the ways to communicate between components is described in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution for this problem would be creating a service that contains a rxjs subject so that the first component can subscribe and the second can emit values to inform the other one that it should call the function

EXAMPLE

```
export class ComponentOne {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.subject.asObservable().subscribe(() => this.myRoleClick())
    }

    myRoleClick() {
        // DO something
    }
}

export class ComponentTwo() {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    myRole() {
        this.myService.subject.next();
    }
}

export class MyService {
    subject = new Subject<void>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest approach is to build a service (I.e. RoleService) which you use in both components. From your first component, invoke the method on your service, create an observable on your service which you emit a value to.  In your second component subscribe to that observable. Make sure you provide your service high in your structure (for instance your app.module.ts) so your components will use the exact same instance of this service object.